# Within an Ember Model, how do I specify the name of an api's object's attribute when it's different from the attribute name of the Ember model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to set up a hasMany relationship for my Style model (hasMany('color_style')), and from what I understand of the documentation, it looks for a style attribute on ColorStyle instances, but my api is sending the attribute style_id, not style.  How do I tell the ColorStyle model to read the style_id attribute from the api into the style attribute of the local model (and to translate it back when sending requests)?

The JSON from the api:

```
{
    id:1,
    color_id:1,
    style_id:1,
    customer_id:1,
    active_flag:null,
    created_at:"2015-02-13T22:35:23.857Z",
    updated_at:"2015-02-13T22:35:23.857Z"
}
```

The Ember Model:

```
App.ColorStyle = DS.Model.extend({
    color:    DS.belongsTo('color'),    // should be tied to color_id from api
    style:    DS.belongsTo('style'),    // should be tied to style_id from api
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer'), // should be tied to customer_id from api
    active_flag: DS.attr('boolean'),
    created_at:  DS.attr('date'),
    updated_at:  DS.attr('date')
});
```

Comment: just curious , why take the trouble when you can use same attribute name as there in api ?

Comment: @AnilMaurya, yes, that does work, but I am trying to get my hasMany relationship on my Status model to work, and my understanding is that the many part of the hasMany relationship is looking for a 'status' key not 'status_id' [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_one-to-many)

Comment: hmmm, ember seems so complicated, it's violating DRY.

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: There is not an error message, the hasMany key just doesn't return any matches (even though I can manually confirm that there are matches) when I use status_id, and when I use style, the attribute data doesn't make it into the object, it just shows up as null (hence why I am looking for a way to map the style_id data to style)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom serializer, but your code will be much cleaner, if you avoid this:

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractSingle